# HashMap: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.put'

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I've initialized `HashMap#onCreate` method and i want to use `HashMap` in `addLocation` method. Everything looks okay but I don't understand why I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

when I call `locationList#put` method.

Here's my code:

```java
public class InitLocationsOnStartup extends Application implements LocationListener {
    HashMap < String, Double[] > locationList;
    List < StationViewModel > stations;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        stations = new ArrayList < StationViewModel > ();
        locationList = new HashMap < > (); // 
    }

    public void getStations(List < StationViewModel > list) {
        this.stations = list;
        addLocation(locationList);
    }

    public HashMap < String, Double[] > addLocation(HashMap < String, Double[] > locationList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stations.size(); i++) {
            latLong = new Double[] {
                Double.parseDouble(stations.get(i).getLatitude()),
                    Double.parseDouble(stations.get(i).getLongitude())
            };

            if (stations.get(i).getStationName() != null && latLong != null) {
                locationList.put(stations.get(i).getStationName(), latLong);

            }
        }
        return locationList;;
    }
```

Comment: registered your `InitLocationsOnStartup` in manifest?

Comment: yes i did in <application
        android:name=".services.location.InitLocationsOnStartup"

Comment: post complete error message and code

Comment: have you tried debugging? It seems like your locationList is null for some reason (even if you did initialize it in onCreate())

Comment: The whole mistake is about the top.But i add more code to addLocation() @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: How is this possible? @Cargeh

Comment: Does that make sense? `if(locationList==nul){locationList = new HashMap<>();}`

Comment: @more why are you not doing this `HashMap<String,Double[]> locationList = new HashMap<>()` after the class declaration ?

Comment: I did and problem solved.But i got **same error** at another method in this class.I think i have different problem. @Lokesh

Comment: @more In that case it's being used some where else. Can you include that function where it's being used

Comment: @Lokesh he wants to do lazy initialization which is the correct way of initialization, IMHO.

Comment: Since the HashMap locationList is a field level variable, you don't need to explicitly pass it to the method addLocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `addLocation` is being called before the `onCreate()` method is executed.

I guess you are accessing an instance of `InitLocationsOnStartup` which is not managed by the Android framework.

If you have code like:

```
InitLocationsOnStartup startup = new InitLocationsOnStartup();
startup.addLocation(..., ...);
```

You are going to get this `NullPointerException`.

The best way to access this class should be in Android activities using the

```
getApplication()
```

method. You could create a static factory method to access this object in a safe way, like e.g:

```
public static InitLocationsOnStartup getInitLocationsOnStartup(Activity activity) {
    return (InitLocationsOnStartup) activity.getApplication();
}
```

This should get you the right instance of the `InitLocationsOnStartup` class which has been correctly initialized by Android.

This method could then be used from Android activities like this:

```
InitLocationsOnStartup startup = getInitLocationsOnStartup(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I want use in Runnable class.So what i need change this code? Maybe like getInitLocationsOnStartup(Runnable runnable)

Comment: @more You will always need to have a reference to an `android.app.Activity` or `android.app.Service` to be able to call the `getApplication()` method. `Runnable` will not help you, because it is neither an Activity or Service via which you can get the right instance of `InitLocationsOnStartup`. Yet, if the Runnable you implement has a reference to an `android.app.Activity` or `android.app.Service` then you can use that reference to call `getApplication()`.

Comment: @more in other words: make sure that the `Runnable` object you  create has a reference to an Android activity or Android service, so that you can call the `getApplication()` method from either of these.

Comment: Thanks for everything!

Comment: @more You are most welcome :)